# Uvah Letzion schedule on Shabbos

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, shacharis-morning-prayer, mincha-afternoon-prayer, motzei-shabbos

Why don't we say Uvah Letzion on Shabbos by Shacharis and say it by Mincha?

Moreover, we then commence to repeat it by Maariv. Why do we do that?

Comment: The question is really: Why do we say Uva Letzion at mincha instead of shachris on Shabbos?

Comment: Are you asking about the whole prayer (in which case the answer is we do at mincha) or why do we skip the first line and start with VeAtah Kadosh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Kol Bo Siman 40](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15217&st=&pgnum=87) and [Rokeach Siman 362](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21522&st=&pgnum=280) say that we do not say Uva Letziyon by Shacharis on Shabbos due to the elderly people, pregnant woman, and expecting mothers that are there as we do not want to make them wait that much longer to eat. Therefore we say it instead at Mincha.

Regarding saying it on Motzei shabbos the Rokeach says it has to do with the fact that sinners are returning to Geheinom then.

A reason I have heard mentioned in the name of the Avudram (however I have been unable to locate) is that since they used to have sermons immediately prior to Mincha on Shabbos and Yom Tov and the end of the sermon was usually about redemption therefore we say Uva Letzioyon at Mincha.

Comment: The first reason you mention compares amusingly to typical contemporary shul programming, at least in most American shuls I've been in. One mishebeirach for a guy who's got a lot of grandchildren can take longer than Uva Letziyon would.

Comment: I know - as I was writing the answer I am thinking about all the wasted time in Shul, however this is what I could find. I guess we waste only so much time....